# How do I reference a view passed as a prop from some other file for testing(using npm test <filename>)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, redux, es6-modules

I have written my function as follows:

```
 _clickTile = (id, view) => {
      console.log(id);
      console.log(view);
      if (id == this.props.data.answerIndex) {                
        view.zoomOut(250).then((endState) => {
          this.props.setProgress && this.props.setProgress(1)
          this.refs.questionView.zoomIn(250);
          this.props.onScore && this.props.onScore(2)
            this.setState({...this.state,
              statuses: this.state.statuses.map(()=>'Neutral')})
              view.zoomIn(250);
            this.props.onEnd()
        })
      } else {
        view.shake(250);
      }
    }
```

In this function I'm getting id and view of a particular tile being clicked but while testing I'm unable to reference the view.

The test case that I wrote for this is:

```
it('Adds scores correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Quiz 
      data= {{
        question: 'F',
        choices: ['P', 'R', 'F', 'A'],
        answerIndex: 2  
      }}
      style= {{
          width: width,
          height: height
      }}
      setprogress={() => {}}
      onScore={(score) => { this.props.dispatch(addMyScore(score)) }}
      onEnd={() => { this.setState(...this.state, { gameOver: true }) }}
      />
    ).getInstance()
    tree.componentWillReceiveProps(tree.props)
    tree._initBoard(tree.props)
    tree._clickTile('1', 'view')   
    tree._onStatusChange('1', 'view', 'Neutral', 'Selected')
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
```

and on executing this test code what I'm getting is that the lines 9,10,11 and 12 from the _clickTile function are not being covered.

Does anyone have any idea on how to reference the view?